# Put dockerfile at top level folder of solution

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I have a Visual Studio solution with two projects. I would like to have the Dockerfile at the same level as my solution file (sln) instead of having it inside my API project (default behavior). I have tried several options, even adding to my API project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DockerfileContext>../Dockerfile</DockerfileContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, Visual Studio is complaining "Error    CTC1023 No Dockerfile could be found. Please make sure you have a Dockerfile called 'Dockerfile' adjacent to the project file"

Is it possible to have Docker integration with Visual Studio and place dockerfile at sln level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer, will post it just in case someone face the same situation.

I added the following attribute in the API project csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!--Other properties ... -> 
    <DockerfileFile>../Dockerfile</DockerfileFile>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Where *../Dockerfile* is the relative path to the dockerfile from the main project.
Now it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder though why we both seem to be the only ones with this problem. :D

Comment: 2 years later I had the same problem for similar reason: to configure an Azure Devops build pipeline for my container, I needed my Dockerfile in the solution root folder. Now that it's the age of ChatGPT, I used it, only to be steered wrong and given the incorrect Property Group element (<DockerfileContext>). This answer has the correct element and solution.